# How to squash commits in one branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, rebase

I made a branch of trunk and been submitting/committing lots of changes. Every so often I would update the branch by merging from trunk (eg. 20 commits, then a merge-update, 20 more commits then a merge-update, etc).

Now I would like to squash everything in my branch. How can I do this (using either Git Extensions or console)?

I tried typing:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~200
```

but I don't know how many commits to squash. I tried counting the commits in Git Extensions but it's hard to see since it shows a mixture of everything from branch commits and trunk commits. The menu "Show current branch only" doesn't help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To rebase all commits made since branching out from `master` you might use the following command:

```
git rebase -i `git merge-base HEAD master`
```

[`git merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) finds the closest common ancestor between your current branch and the master (i.e. the last commit that is available on both).

After passing it to the `git rebase` you get list of all commits since branching out from `master` (or whatever branch you will put in there) which you can freely squash.

Note: this will not differentiate between yours and merge commits, but as far as I understand that's not what you're looking for.

Note 2: beware that rewriting history after pushing to remote repo might require force-pushing, which is very troublesome when working on a single branch with other people.

Comment: I am the only one working on the branch... so your method/way should be fine right?

Comment: excellent, it seems to have rearranged the commits and I can see all the commits nicely sorted and together...
I then used tortoisegit, selected all my commits and "combine"...

Comment: though, do you think tortoisegit - combine commits is the same as squash command? what would've been the equivalent squash commandline?

Comment: Actually, when you rebase a branch using method above, you can just replace the `pick` keyword with `squash` in each line, which will cause the squash to be performed on all commits.

Comment: This link might be helpful - the guy does exactly that, but with 3 latest commits. https://www.devroom.io/2011/07/05/git-squash-your-latests-commits-into-one/

Comment: This is good, but I think have to be careful, and yes, I must force push back to origin (remote), otherwise if I pull/merge, I get duplicates

Comment: Exactly, but you should always be careful with rewriting git history. Actually, I would advise to avoid it when possible, but that's just an opinion.

Answer (score 8):

Since you need to squash so many commits, you can use the way below:

Assume `myBranch` original like:

```
...M---A---B---...---N---...---X  myBranch
```

If you need to squash commits from `A` to `X`, you just need to find the parent of commit `A` (as commit `M` in above graph), and then use the commands

```
git checkout myBranch
git reset --soft <commit id for M>
git commit -m 'squash commit from A to X'
```

Then the commits on `myBranch` will be (the squash commit is `S`):

```
...M---S  myBranch
```

Comment: how can I find the commit ID number?

Comment: There are many ways, such as `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all` and `gitk --all`.

Comment: is the commit #
the long SHA1 ID?
or the short one which I see from git log?

Comment: The hash ID is the long one, but *any* hash ID can be shortened down to as little as four characters *as long as the result is unambiguous*. For instance if the hash ID is `feeddad1deadc0ffeebedbeadbadcafebeef4cab...` you can use just `feed` as long as nothing else in your repository *also* starts with `feed`. If something does, you might need `feedd` or `feedda` or `feeddad` or even `feeddad1dea`. When Git shortens these IDs, it generally (though not always) gives you one that's suitable for putting back into Git.

Comment: @AndWan both long and short string are stand for the same commit id. A commit id (sha-1) is calculate with 40 hex characters, you can also use more than 4 characters at start to repensent (as torek said).

Comment: This works well for my use case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This code will rebase in interactive mode your current branch commits and it will put rebased commits on top of master

```
git rebase -i HEAD~$(git rev-list --count origin/master..) && git pull --rebase origin master
```